# Is here okay to post a question about computer science lore?

Tags: discussion

I'm having a hard time thinking where might be the right site for a question about half-remembered computer science lore: I vaguely remember a story about a `C` guru and a `Unix` scripting guru challenging each other to solve a certain problem (the details of which escape me). The short of it is that the `C` guy (who was no slouch) came up with a valid, but complicated solution, requiring pages of code, and the `Unix` guy came up with a one- (or few-) liner that consisted of chaining together some of the standard `Unix` utilities. **Is there an existing Stack Exchange site suitable for questions on computer science "lore" like this?** (I'm asking in order to find the story details - the remembered details that I just described weren't sufficient for google to find a hit)

(Funnily: the Science Fiction & Fantasy Exchange is a great site where the community amazingly comes up with finds to authors' half-remembered details of books, movies, and such)

Comment: I would try [so].

Comment: There may not be a good place on the network for questions of this type, at all; this particular one is not about computer _science_ but about programming, it seems, so it'd be offtopic here anyway.

Comment: It might be this story: [Revisiting Knuth and McIlroy's word count programs](https://franklinchen.com/blog/2011/12/08/revisiting-knuth-and-mcilroys-word-count-programs/) "*Knuth came up with a typically clever, lengthy, low-level implementation. McIlroy then somewhat perversely wrote a six-line shell script that did the job, basically changing the subject away from literate programming and toward a critique of Knuth’s doing something low-level and complicated when unnecessary.*"

Comment: @HendrikJan - I believe that is it -- thank you!

Comment: @StoneThrow Although it solves your problem, it still doesn't answer your question. By accident I discovered we now have a SE for[History of Science and Mathematics](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/), which might be appropriate?

Comment: @HendrikJan - sounds like a good candidate, indeed! I will ask there to confirm.